# Why do I get @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.1 instead of 12.2.1?

Tags: angular, npm

Since 12.2 started popping up, I've not been able to build.  Neither behind the company's Artifactory, nor from the internet.  None of the following commands have been to any avail:

```
npm cache clean --force
rm -fr node_modules/
rm -fr ~/.npm/
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install -g @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest
```

My current (after some fiddling and removing implicit dependencies) package.json is

```json
{
  "name": "ngapp",
  "version": "7.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",

    "@angular/flex-layout": "~12.0.0-beta.34",

    "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker": "^12.0.0",

    "core-js": "^3.16.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "~12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "~2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "moment": "2.29.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.0",

    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.2.0",

    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^16.4.12",

    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.2.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

The error report shows all dependents as wanting "~12.2.0" or "^12.0.0" or ">=12.0.0", which should currently match "12.2.1".  Yet it mysteriously falls back to "12.1.1".
I get this eresolve-report.txt:

```
# npm resolution error report

2021-08-11T20:17:49.912Z

While resolving: ngapp@7.0.0
Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.1
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
  dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.2.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.2.0" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@12.2.1
node_modules/@angular/core
  peer @angular/core@"12.2.1" from @angular/service-worker@12.2.1
  node_modules/@angular/service-worker
    peerOptional @angular/service-worker@"^12.0.0 || ^12.2.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.1
    node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
      dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.2.0" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:
```

```json
{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "edge": {
    "type": "dev",
    "name": "@angular-devkit/build-angular",
    "spec": "~12.2.0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "location": "…/ngapp"
    }
  },
  "dep": {
    "name": "@angular-devkit/build-angular",
    "version": "12.2.1",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "aco-ngapp",
      "version": "7.0.0",
      "path": "…/ngapp"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "dev",
        "name": "@angular-devkit/build-angular",
        "spec": "~12.2.0",
        "error": "INVALID",
        "from": {
          "location": "…/ngapp"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "current": {
    "name": "@angular-devkit/build-angular",
    "version": "12.1.1",
    "location": "node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "dev",
        "name": "@angular-devkit/build-angular",
        "spec": "~12.2.0",
        "error": "INVALID",
        "from": {
          "location": "…/ngapp"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "peerConflict": {
    "current": {
      "name": "@angular/core",
      "version": "12.1.1",
      "location": "node_modules/@angular/core",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "peer",
          "name": "@angular/core",
          "spec": "12.1.1",
          "from": {
            "name": "@angular/animations",
            "version": "12.1.1",
            "location": "node_modules/@angular/animations",
            "isWorkspace": false,
            "dependents": [
              {
                "type": "prod",
                "name": "@angular/animations",
                "spec": "~12.2.0",
                "error": "INVALID",
                "from": {
                  "location": "…/ngapp"
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/animations",
                "spec": "^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/material",
                  "version": "12.1.1",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/material",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "@angular/material",
                      "spec": "~12.2.0",
                      "error": "INVALID",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peerOptional",
                "name": "@angular/animations",
                "spec": "12.1.1",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/platform-browser",
                  "version": "12.1.1",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/platform-browser",
                      "spec": ">=12.0.0",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/flex-layout",
                        "version": "12.0.0-beta.34",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/flex-layout",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/flex-layout",
                            "spec": "~12.0.0-beta.34",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/platform-browser",
                      "spec": "12.1.1",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/forms",
                        "version": "12.1.1",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/forms",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/forms",
                            "spec": "~12.2.0",
                            "error": "INVALID",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "type": "peer",
                            "name": "@angular/forms",
                            "spec": "^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0",
                            "from": {
                              "name": "@angular/material",
                              "version": "12.1.1",
                              "location": "node_modules/@angular/material",
                              "isWorkspace": false,
                              "dependents": [
                                {
                                  "type": "prod",
                                  "name": "@angular/material",
                                  "spec": "~12.2.0",
                                  "error": "INVALID",
                                  "from": {
                                    "location": "…/ngapp"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/platform-browser",
                      "spec": "12.1.1",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
                        "version": "12.1.1",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
                            "spec": "~12.2.0",
                            "error": "INVALID",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/platform-browser",
                      "spec": "12.1.1",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/router",
                        "version": "12.1.1",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/router",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/router",
                            "spec": "~12.2.0",
                            "error": "INVALID",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "peer",
          "name": "@angular/core",
          "spec": "^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0",
          "from": {
            "name": "@angular/cdk",
            "version": "12.1.1",
            "location": "node_modules/@angular/cdk",
            "isWorkspace": false,
            "dependents": [
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/cdk",
                "spec": "^12.0.0",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/flex-layout",
                  "version": "12.0.0-beta.34",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/flex-layout",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "@angular/flex-layout",
                      "spec": "~12.0.0-beta.34",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/cdk",
                "spec": "12.1.1",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/material",
                  "version": "12.1.1",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/material",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "@angular/material",
                      "spec": "~12.2.0",
                      "error": "INVALID",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/cdk",
                "spec": "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker",
                  "version": "12.0.0",
                  "location": "node_modules/@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker",
                      "spec": "^12.0.0",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "peer",
          "name": "@angular/core",
          "spec": "12.1.1",
          "from": {
            "name": "@angular/common",
            "version": "12.1.1",
            "location": "node_modules/@angular/common",
            "isWorkspace": false,
            "dependents": [
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/common",
                "spec": "^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/cdk",
                  "version": "12.1.1",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/cdk",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/cdk",
                      "spec": "^12.0.0",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/flex-layout",
                        "version": "12.0.0-beta.34",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/flex-layout",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/flex-layout",
                            "spec": "~12.0.0-beta.34",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/cdk",
                      "spec": "12.1.1",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/material",
                        "version": "12.1.1",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/material",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/material",
                            "spec": "~12.2.0",
                            "error": "INVALID",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/cdk",
                      "spec": "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker",
                        "version": "12.0.0",
                        "location": "node_modules/@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker",
                            "spec": "^12.0.0",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/common",
                "spec": ">=12.0.0",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/flex-layout",
                  "version": "12.0.0-beta.34",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/flex-layout",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "@angular/flex-layout",
                      "spec": "~12.0.0-beta.34",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/common",
                "spec": "12.1.1",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/forms",
                  "version": "12.1.1",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/forms",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "@angular/forms",
                      "spec": "~12.2.0",
                      "error": "INVALID",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/forms",
                      "spec": "^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/material",
                        "version": "12.1.1",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/material",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/material",
                            "spec": "~12.2.0",
                            "error": "INVALID",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/common",
                "spec": "^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/material",
                  "version": "12.1.1",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/material",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "@angular/material",
                      "spec": "~12.2.0",
                      "error": "INVALID",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/common",
                "spec": "12.1.1",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/platform-browser",
                  "version": "12.1.1",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/platform-browser",
                      "spec": ">=12.0.0",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/flex-layout",
                        "version": "12.0.0-beta.34",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/flex-layout",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/flex-layout",
                            "spec": "~12.0.0-beta.34",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/platform-browser",
                      "spec": "12.1.1",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/forms",
                        "version": "12.1.1",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/forms",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/forms",
                            "spec": "~12.2.0",
                            "error": "INVALID",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "type": "peer",
                            "name": "@angular/forms",
                            "spec": "^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0",
                            "from": {
                              "name": "@angular/material",
                              "version": "12.1.1",
                              "location": "node_modules/@angular/material",
                              "isWorkspace": false,
                              "dependents": [
                                {
                                  "type": "prod",
                                  "name": "@angular/material",
                                  "spec": "~12.2.0",
                                  "error": "INVALID",
                                  "from": {
                                    "location": "…/ngapp"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/platform-browser",
                      "spec": "12.1.1",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
                        "version": "12.1.1",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
                            "spec": "~12.2.0",
                            "error": "INVALID",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "peer",
                      "name": "@angular/platform-browser",
                      "spec": "12.1.1",
                      "from": {
                        "name": "@angular/router",
                        "version": "12.1.1",
                        "location": "node_modules/@angular/router",
                        "isWorkspace": false,
                        "dependents": [
                          {
                            "type": "prod",
                            "name": "@angular/router",
                            "spec": "~12.2.0",
                            "error": "INVALID",
                            "from": {
                              "location": "…/ngapp"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/common",
                "spec": "12.1.1",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
                  "version": "12.1.1",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
                      "spec": "~12.2.0",
                      "error": "INVALID",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/common",
                "spec": "12.1.1",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@angular/router",
                  "version": "12.1.1",
                  "location": "node_modules/@angular/router",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "@angular/router",
                      "spec": "~12.2.0",
                      "error": "INVALID",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/common",
                "spec": "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0",
                "from": {
                  "name": "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker",
                  "version": "12.0.0",
                  "location": "node_modules/@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker",
                      "spec": "^12.0.0",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "peer",
                "name": "@angular/common",
                "spec": "^12.0.0",
                "from": {
                  "name": "ngx-cookie-service",
                  "version": "12.0.0",
                  "location": "node_modules/ngx-cookie-service",
                  "isWorkspace": false,
                  "dependents": [
                    {
                      "type": "prod",
                      "name": "ngx-cookie-service",
                      "spec": "~12.0.0",
                      "from": {
                        "location": "…/ngapp"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
    …
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false,
  "isMine": true
}
```

Comment: did you solve this @Daniel ?